# Threading won't work on Godaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey guys, I'm sure this doesn't only apply to godaddy, but it may help illuminate the issue. The issue is that I need my webpage to run a thread in the background, and everything works fine when I do it in my local IIS, but when I upload it to godaddy's servers it simply doesn't work.

The code:

```
Thread threadFind = new Thread(LoadFind);
threadFind.Start();
```

However, this still works:

```
LoadFind();
```

Thank you.

Comment: ..and what error do you get? Have you contacted GoDaddy?

Comment: IIS versions on your machine and on the GoDaddy server?

Comment: Unless there's some very strange preprocessor magic around, `new Thread` is a syntax error in `C`. Please retag or show the preprocessor macros

Comment: @pmg: talking about c# here dude.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can think of is the "Full Trust" mode as godaddy doesn't support Full Trust and this may be a result of it.

On a related note - you might want to look at these articles to get a feel of how you can do async pages in ASP.NET..

http://weblogs.asp.net/plip/archive/2005/01/20/357598.aspx

[Threading in asp.net crashing server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333644/threading-in-asp-net-crashing-server)

Comment: I called godaddy and you're right, it is a full trust issue. I tried some of the code in the links you provided, namely the  AddOnPreRenderCompleteAsync method, but for some reason it's not threading as expected. What I really need to do is execute a web service in the background, but in the mean time let the page response complete. Any ideas how to do that without full trust?

Comment: @Rob - sorry.. I missed this comment.. Here is the link which can give you a working sample http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2010/04/02/calling-web-service-functions-asynchronously-from-a-web-page.aspx