# Task.Run with parameters not working in ASP MVC but works without parameters passed in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, iis-7

I have the code below which works when there are no parameters to the method but does not work when I pass in parameters. I initially thought the parameters were being lost when the context in IIS was lost, so I did a deep copy of the same thing still happens. I tried to also log the errors or messages but same thing - it never calls the method to do the task. The initial log messages are written successful, but not the log message in the method  I would like to add this happens in an asp mvc project. I've been on this for 2 days, all over stackoverflow and google with no solution. I added the thread sleep to give the background thread to maybe start but it didn't work. The currentcontroller inherits from the basecontroller class. The logger uses log4net. The logging works, I see entries in the database. The thread.sleep was added to see if it fixes the issue by making the parent thread wait for the background thread to start. Any ideas?

```
public class MainController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ProcessSynchronization(int sourceId, string[] cities)
    {
        var ret = false;
        try
        {              

            if (sourceId == 1)
            { 
                var cityDeep = (string[])cities.Clone();
                Logger.Info("ABout to start BeginSynchronization ..");

                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Logger.Info("ABout to start BeginSynchronization enter..");

                    BeginSynchronization(cityDeep);
                });


                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                ret = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(LogUtility.BuildExceptionMessage(ex), ex);
            return Json(new { result = ret, responseText = "Customer could not be activated." });
        }
        return Json(new { result = ret, responseText = "Synchronization started." });
    }

    private void BeginSynchronization (string[] cities)
    {
        Logger.Info("BeginSynchronization entry processing..");

    }
}

public class BaseController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get logger
    /// </summary>
    protected ILog Logger
    {
        get { return LogManager.GetLogger(GetType()); }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `Thread.Sleep`? How is `Logger` being declared? Why are you calling an instance method inside another Thread (created with `Task.Factory.StartNew`)? It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Also, please add the entire Controller code and double check if any exception is thrown.

Comment: I have added more details. What do you mean by calling an instance method? This is a private method in the same controller class.

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify you method with `async`/`await` keywords.

```
public async JsonResult ProcessSynchronization(int sourceId, string[] cities)
{
    var ret = false;
    try
    {              

        if (sourceId == 1)
        { 
            var cityDeep = (string[])cities.Clone();
            Logger.Info("ABout to start BeginSynchronization ..");

            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Logger.Info("ABout to start BeginSynchronization enter..");

                BeginSynchronization(cityDeep);
            });


            ret = true;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(LogUtility.BuildExceptionMessage(ex), ex);
        return Json(new { result = ret, responseText = "Customer could not be activated." });
    }
    return Json(new { result = ret, responseText = "Synchronization started." });
}
```

Without `async`/`await`:

```
public JsonResult ProcessSynchronization(int sourceId, string[] cities)
{
    var ret = false;
    try
    {              

        if (sourceId == 1)
        { 
            var cityDeep = (string[])cities.Clone();
            Logger.Info("ABout to start BeginSynchronization ..");

            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Logger.Info("ABout to start BeginSynchronization enter..");

                BeginSynchronization(cityDeep);
            });
            thread.Start();


            ret = true;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(LogUtility.BuildExceptionMessage(ex), ex);
        return Json(new { result = ret, responseText = "Customer could not be activated." });
    }
    return Json(new { result = ret, responseText = "Synchronization started." });
}
```

Comment: I don't want the controller to wait for the task to complete. I want it to be fire and forget, will the await not wait for it?

Comment: Don't use `Task.Factory.StartNew` anymore. Use `Task.Run`.

Comment: The problem here is the following. The action is executed in a thread pool. When the action completes the thread is returned to thread pool and task is just scheduled but not executed. If you replace Task.Factory.StartNew with new Thread(...) it should work fine

Comment: No, that does not work. I have tried your code above and the same issue happens, it does not start.

Comment: new Thread(..).Start() explicitly runs a new thread so it does not depend on action execution.
Is sourceId equals to 1?

Comment: Yes, sourceid is 1. also the message ABout to start BeginSynchronization .. is written to the database.

Comment: Just to add, all the old and new codes works on localhost but not when deployed to production server on godaddy.

Comment: it's a completely different question:)
I think it refers this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714041/threading-wont-work-on-godaddy